# Custom post types and default posts at the same installation

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy, permalinks

Is it appropriate to use under the same Wordpress installation custom post types and default posts?

I have a website with many default posts, I need now to intergrate a custom post type and a custom taxonomy. In addition I need to show my taxonomy in my permalinks and I want that my default posts keep using the same old permalink stucture : `/%category%/%postname%.`

I have read about making taxonomies appear in my permalink using `post_type_link` filter hook  and a call back function that rewrite `%taxonomy_name%` to `taxonomy_name`. But  to make this achieved, I think I need to go to general settings and put under custom permalink: `%taxonomy_name%/%post_name%`, what maybe will affect my default posts permalink structure.

If it is possible to use under the same installation of Wordpress custom post types and normal posts. If so, how to manage permalinks under general settings?

Your help is appreciated. I am new in custom post types and taxonomies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can use custom post types and default post type at the same Wordpress website without any problem concerning permalinks structures.You can have under the permalink settings a new area where you can manage permalink structure of custom post type separately.

the plugin to use is: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/